# datagrip2023.3.2 connect shardingsphere proxy of mysql8.0.28, remind Unable to implement EnumerableSort

Tags: proxy, mysql-8.0, datagrip, shardingsphere

**1. datagrip2023.3.2 connect shardingsphere proxy  of mysql8.0.28, it is successful, but can't show tables when I click on databasename, remind Unable to implement EnumerableSort;**
**2. But dbeaver can't show tables**
**3. datagrip2023.3.2 connect shardingsphere proxy  of mysql5.7.43 successfully, and can show tables when I click on databasename**

mysql version: 8.0.28
shardingsphere proxy version: 5.3.2
shardingsphere proxy driver version: mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar
datagrip version: 2023.3.2
datagrip jdbc driver version: mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar

connect error:
`[HY000][30000] Unknown exception: Unable to implement EnumerableSort(sort0=[$0], sort1=[$1], sort2=[$2], dir0=[ASC], dir1=[ASC], dir2=[ASC]): rowcount = 3.375, cumulative cost = {106.75 rows, 4948.792031905426 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 99 EnumerableCalc(expr#0..30=[{inputs}], expr#31=[null:NULL], expr#32=[1], expr#33=[_UTF-8'FUNCTION'], expr#34=[LIKE($t4, $t33)], expr#35=[CAST($t2):VARCHAR CHARACTER SET "UTF-8"], expr#36=[_UTF-8'clitest':VARCHAR CHARACTER SET "UTF-8"], expr#37=[=($t35, $t36)], expr#38=[IS NOT NULL($t3)], expr#39=[AND($t34, $t37, $t38)], FUNCTION_CAT=[$t2], FUNCTION_SCHEM=[$t31], FUNCTION_NAME=[$t3], REMARKS=[$t26], FUNCTION_TYPE=[$t32], SPECIFIC_NAME=[$t3], $condition=[$t39]): rowcount = 3.375, cumulative cost = {103.375 rows, 4801.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 98 EnumerableTableScan(table=[[INFORMATION_SCHEMA, ROUTINES]]): rowcount = 100.0, cumulative cost = {100.0 rows, 101.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 92.`  
my proxy config:
`localProxyServer: authority: users: - user: test password: 123456 privilege: type: ALL_PERMITTED props: sql-federation-type: ADVANCED`

give me some idea to make datagrip show tables when connect cshardingsphere proxy

Comment: Suspecting this to be a bug. Please report your issue on our tracker 

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE

and attach the idea log from Help - Show Log in Files. We'll take it from there.

Comment: It looks similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-16961/DataGrip-not-connection-shardingsphere-proxy-DB ...

Comment: @xiaoche, have you tried to set *Introspect using JDBC metadata* in your data source *Expert Options* in *Advanced* tab?